# Change the attribute of textarea in jsp using java class

Tags: java, jsp

I want to change the attribute of these textareas using java class. As you can see textareas are disable by default. I want to this to be enable if user can't find registered TIN in database. Here's my code:

**jsp:**

```
<label style="font-size: 17px;">Registered Name</label><br><br>         
<textarea disabled id="tpName" name="tpName" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;">${name}</textarea>   
<br><br>
<label style="font-size: 17px;">Address</label><br><br>         
<textarea disabled id="tpAddress" name="tpAddress" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;">${address}</textarea>
```

**class:**

```
private String tpTin;
private String tpName;  
private String tpAddress;
private TblTaxPayment tbltaxpayment;

public String getTpTin() {
    return tpTin;
}
public String getTpName() {
    return tpName;
}
public String getTpAddress() {
    return tpAddress;
}
public void setTpTin(String tpTin) {
    this.tpTin = tpTin;
}
public void setTpName(String tpName) {
    this.tpName = tpName;
}
public void setTpAddress(String tpAddress) {
    this.tpAddress = tpAddress;
}

private HttpServletRequest request;

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
    this.request = request;
}
public TblTaxPayment getTblTaxPayment() {
    return tbltaxpayment;
}
public void setTblTaxPayment(TblTaxPayment tbltaxpayment) {
    this.tbltaxpayment = tbltaxpayment;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public String execute() throws Exception {

    Debugger.border();
    Debugger.startDebug(this.getClass().toString());

    String tax = request.getParameter("tpTin");

    TblTaxPaymentDAO tdao = DAOFactory.getDaoManager(TblTaxPayment.class);
    TblTaxPayment t = null;
    t = tdao.findbyTIN(tax.replace("-", ""));
    tbltaxpayment = (TblTaxPayment) t;

    try{

            Debugger.print("TIN : "+tax);
            if(tax != null) {

                tpTin = tbltaxpayment.getTpTin();                                       
                tpName = tbltaxpayment.getTpName();
                tpAddress = tbltaxpayment.getTpAddress();

                String tin = tpTin;
                String name = tpName;
                String address = tpAddress;

                request.setAttribute("tin", tin);
                request.setAttribute("name", name);
                request.setAttribute("address", address);

                return SUCCESS;
            }else{
                request.setAttribute("name", true);
                request.setAttribute("address", true);              
                return SUCCESS;
            }


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Debugger.endDebug(this.getClass().toString());
        Debugger.border();
        return ERROR;
    }

}
```

}

what I did. I set the attribute to true to be able to change the property/attribute of textareas in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

If your Java class contains the logic that determines whether or not the textareas are enabled, you must first have your Java class store that state somewhere that the JSP can access. You have a number of options: You can set it as a request attribute, e.g.

```
request.setAttribute("nameRequired", true /* or false */); 
request.setAttribute("addressRequired", true /* or false */);
```

You could store flags in your Java class and make them available via getters:

```
boolean nameRequired;
boolean addressRequired;

public String execute () throws Exception {
    ...
    nameRequired = true /* or false */;
    addressRequired = true /* or false */;
    ...
}

public boolean isNameRequired () {
    return nameRequired;
}

public boolean isAddressRequired () {
    return addressRequired;
}
```

For either of the above you could also further isolate business logic from UI by having the class return a business state and having the UI decide if name or address is required, e.g.;

```
request.setAttribute("haveTaxInfo", false /* or true */);
```

Or whatever -- semantics.

In any case, the information that the JSP requires to determine the textarea state is now accessible by the JSP. Then, in your JSP, you simply write the `disabled` attribute as appropriate:

```
<%

// option 1: if you used request attributes:
boolean nameRequired = Boolean.TRUE.equals(request.getAttribute("nameRequired")); 
boolean addressRequired = Boolean.TRUE.equals(request.getAttribute("addressRequired"));

// option 2: or, if you used class fields:
boolean nameRequired = businessClass.isNameRequired(); 
boolean addressRequired = businessClass.isAddressRequired();

// option 3: or,if you used the business state in a request attribute: 
boolean haveTaxInfo = Boolean.TRUE.equals(request.getAttribute("haveTaxInfo"));
boolean nameRequired = !haveTaxInfo;    // if we don't have the tax info then the name
boolean addressRequired = !haveTaxInfo; // and address are required.

%>

<textarea <%=(nameRequired?"":"disabled")%> id="tpName" name="tpName" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;">${name}</textarea>   
<textarea <%=(addressRequired?"":"disabled")%> id="tpAddress" name="tpAddress" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;">${address}</textarea>
```

The key point to take home here is that you can use the `<%= ... %>` JSP tags to control whether or not you write "disabled" to the output. You can use a conditional expression in those tags based on some boolean value, and that boolean value must somehow be communicated from your business class to the JSP (either by a request attribute, or a getter, or something).

Hope that helps.